# Questions about Irobot Create

Tags: mobile-robot, irobot-create

I'm interested in getting a Create for a project I'll be working on, and wanted some information about it from somebody that already has one:

1. How much weight can it safely carry? I talked with Irobot's tech support and they told me the maximum is 5lb, but searching on the internet it seems like this limit is actually not as strict as it appears to be. I'm asking because I'd need to put a 3kg laptop on top of it, which would mean ~3.5-4kg if you also consider the kinect and eventual supports for both. I guess I could use a netbook and send the data I need to another computer, but I wanted to avoid the additional overhead of the wireless link.
2. For how long does it run using AA batteries? I'm inclined on not getting the battery pack, since I'd be using the robot in europe, so I'd also need a transformer if I went with the battery pack option.

Thanks!

Comment: Stack exchange works best when you ask a single question at once. It is usually Ok to ask a question with a subsidiary, related question, but two completely separate and independent questions are better asked as two questions here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The weight of just the 6.6 pound laptop is already 32% over capacity, so you may need to consider lightening the load. If not then you risk lower performance, higher stresses on the robot and possibly even burning out one or more motors under stress testing.

On the matter of battery life, according to the [iRobot Create Manual](http://www.irobot.com/filelibrary/pdfs/hrd/create/Create%20Manual_Final.pdf):

> Alkaline batteries will power the robot (on a hard floor with no payloads or
>   attachments) for up to 1.5 hours if the robot is constantly moving.

So this is less than half the run time of the APS battery:

> The iRobot Create robot (without a payload or other attachments) will run for
>   up to 3.5 hours with a fully charged APS battery.